# what is the word for the "thank you" section of a document called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

So in a typical letter document that may span **multiple** pages

At the end of the content, there is paragraph for "thank you" or "signing off"

This paragraph/section only appear **once**, at the **end** of the content

however it is NOT a "footer" that appears on every page (as in MS Word treats footer to appear on every page)

i have been resorting to calling it "pre-footer" but wonder if there is a proper term for it

*i am just trying to create a letter template, and there is a section for signing-off/thank you which i am trying to appropriately name the section*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how common it is, but (at least) according to *the balance careers*, the word you're looking for is **closing**:

Their [Sample Letter Format](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/sample-letter-format-2063479) consists of these sections:

- Contact Information (Sender)
- Date
- Contact Information (Recipient)
- Greeting
- Body of Letter
- **Closing**
- Signature

The article [Formal Letter Closing Examples](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/formal-letter-closing-examples-2062307)  also uses the term **Complimentary Close**.

Answer (score 3):

I think from the question you may mean the sign off... Yours sincerely etc...

In which case, most would just say the sign off or the end but I think its technically the **valediction**

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction?wprov=sfla1)

Answer (score 1):

In any book it is called 
***ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS***.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acknowledgment/:

***acknowledgment***

: recognition or favorable notice of an act or achievement

// received 
acknowledgment for his charitable works

: a thing done or given in recognition of something received

// an author's acknowledgments of assistance

Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

''This part of the profile includes a foreword by the ECE Executive Secretary, a preface, *acknowledgements*, and an executive summary.''

Comment: I don't think "acknowledgments" is suitable, according to the OP's request: “*i am just trying to create **a letter template**, and there is **a section for signing-off/thank you** which i am trying to appropriately name the section!*”